# Backup and restore database along with user/group/roles and permissions in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are having some problem in server hosting SQL server 2005. We are required to take backup of all the databases and restore the same once the

```
window 2003 server and sql server 2005
```

is reinstalled.
We also need to restore all the `users/groups/roles` and permissions as it is which were there earlier.
Please guide the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The database securables are backed up with the database.

What you will have to do is to script and recreate the logins. If the logins are SQL Server logins (not the windows logins, ie), the trick is to create them with the same SIDs as before to avoid orphaned database users (this can bi fixed manually, but it's much easier to recreate the same-SID logins).

Here's the article on MS support describing the procedure in detail:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992

Comment: By backup - do you mean full backup or also differential and log backups please?